# Activity orientation restore

Tags: android, android-activity

There is an Activity named `PlayActivity` which is used to play videos, and I set this activity to use the `landscape` model by xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.PlayActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Now once I enter the activity  from another Activity say it is `MainActivity`, the `PlayActivity` will use the `landscape` model as expected, however once I hit the back button to return to `MainActivity`, I found that the `MainActivity` is changed to `landscape` too, how to avoid this?

Comment: did you set android:screenOrientation="portrait" for MainActivity?

Comment: No, I did not set that for `MainActivity`. I want the activity which trigger the `PlayActivity` should stay with the orientation as that when it start the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your MainActiviy activity in the portrait, since you can configure the whole application in one direction to customize each one of them to leave an example of how serious greetings.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PlayActivity""
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
          />
```